# Rectangle in Xamarin forms does not honor the HeightRequest

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set the `HeightRequest` of a Rectangle to 10, but the height instead fills the entire height of the Grid. What am I doing wrong or is this a bug in Xamarin Forms.  I am using Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012.

[image]

```
<Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <shapes:Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                          Fill="Green"

                                          StrokeThickness="0"
                                          WidthRequest="50"
                                          HeightRequest="10"/>

                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                               Style="{StaticResource Subtitle1TextStyle}"
                               Text="Green area: ideally, your average lines would stay within your target range." />

                        <shapes:Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                                          Fill="Black"
                                          StrokeThickness="0"
                                          WidthRequest="50"
                                          HeightRequest="10"/>

                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                               Style="{StaticResource Subtitle1TextStyle}"
                               Text="Black line: The black line has a lot of text on this line. The Rectangle height keeps growing even though the height request has been set to 10." />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are putting the Label and the black rectangle on the same Row (which have it `Height` set to Auto), it means it will take the maximum `Height` of the elements in that Row which in your case is the `Label`, thus the rectangle will get the same Height as the `Label` even that you have specified it `HeightRequest`to be 10.

To overcome this create another Row and span the Label over Row 2 and 3, also notice the new simplified syntax for `ColumnDefinition` and `RowDefinition`:

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="auto,auto,auto" ColumnDefinitions="auto,*">

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                   Fill="Green"
                   StrokeThickness="0"
                   WidthRequest="50"
                   HeightRequest="10"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
               Text="Green area: ideally, your average lines would stay within your target range."/>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                   Fill="Black"
                   VerticalOptions="Fill"
                   StrokeThickness="0"
                   WidthRequest="50"
                   HeightRequest="10"/>

        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               TextColor="Black"
               Text="Black line: The black line has a lot of text on this line. The Rectangle height keeps growing even though the height request has been set to 10."/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I ended up doing.  I still think the Grid should honor the HeightRequest of the Rectangle.

Comment: @AdamScroggin If you still want to grid honor the HeightRequest of the Rectangle, you can set the second `<RowDefinition Height="10" />`, then wrap label by using scrollview `<ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Label  />
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollView>`

Comment: Thank you @CherryBu-MSFT. I'm not sure that will work, but I can try. Is this a bug?  Why does the Grid honor the WidthRequest but not the HeightRequest?

Comment: @AdamScroggin  I agree with Cfun's opinion. Auto – the row height or column width is autosized based on the cell contents (Auto in XAML).